# How to get following XML structure using JaxB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have requirement where I need to generate XML having following structure.
Data I am populating from database but this is going to be format for the target XML.
I have created few classes and tried marshalling those bean but I am not able to generate following structure.
Please help.

```
<Component id ="668020">--root element
    <xyz>xyz</xyz>
    <pqr>pqr</pqr>
    <Profile>
        <ABc>abc</ABc>
        <Bcd>bcd</Bcd>  
    </Profile>
    <TwentySeven>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item> 
    </TwentySeven>
    <Hundred>
    <Hundred_One>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <one>1</one>
            <two>2</two>
        </Item> 
    </Hundred_one>
    </Hundred>  
</Component>
```

Comment: Show us your few classes please, than that is how it works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your XML structure to be precise, here are the sample Java class structures you need to follow inorder to work along with JaxB:
This will be your Root element class.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Component {
    private int id;

    private Profile profile;

    private TwentySeven twentySeven;

    private Hundred hundred;

    public Hundred getHundred() {
        return hundred;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setHundred(Hundred hundred) {
        this.hundred = hundred;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /*
     * Same way add @XMLElement annotation to
     * setter methods of profile and twentySeven.
     */

}
```

Other sample classes are as shown below:

```
public class Hundred {
    private List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

public class TwentySeven {
    private List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

public class Item {
    //private <Object of type One>
    //private <Object of type Two>

    /*
     * Write getter setter methods and add annotations
     * accordingly as shown in other sample methods.
     */
}

public class Profile {
    private Abc item;

    public Abc getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setItem(Abc item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    //Bcd also goes in same way
}

public class Abc {
    private String param1;

    private String param2;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
}
```

I hope this should help you get going.

**Note:** The classes and methods written in this example are just samples. You need to modify them according to your needs.

Comment: There is one change in Hundred node

 <Hundred>
  <Hundred_one>
  <Item>
   <one>1</one>
   <two>2</two>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <one>1</one>
   <two>2</two>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <one>1</one>
   <two>2</two>
  </Item>
  </Hundred_one>
 </Hundred>

Comment: how to acheive that

Comment: In that case, create a class called `HundredOne`, cut out the code which is in `Hunderd` class and paste it in `HundredOne`, add `HundredOne` as a class member within `Hundred`, write getters and setters and annotate them accordingly.

Comment: No. I am not able to get it.I tried doing so by creating new class for getting node Hundred_one under Hundred by entering whatever in Hundred into Hundred_one but it failed.

Comment: Thanx for help. I got it finally

Comment: Cool!! I'm glad it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Generate xsd for your xml using any online xsd generator like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output). Then you generate pojos using [this](http://nthieu-java-research.blogspot.in/2013/07/jaxb-using-maven-plugin-xjc-tool-to.html). Then you can do marshalling as well as unmarshalling using jaxb.

One more thing your HUndred tag is wrong at bottom make it Hundred.

Comment: you can also generate using command line. If you want to do that way use http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create XSD
2. with NetBeans create JAXb Bindings
3. Marshall tree:

   ```
           Component1 comp1       = new Component1();
           comp1.setId("668020"); 
           comp1.setXyz("xyz");
           comp1.setPqr("pqr");
           Component1.Profile prof = new Component1.Profile();
           prof.setABc("abc");
           prof.setBcd("bcd");
           comp1.setProfile(prof);
           Component1.TwentySeven tw7 = new Component1.TwentySeven();
           Component1.TwentySeven.Item ite7_1 = new Component1.TwentySeven.Item();
           ite7_1.setOne(1);
           ite7_1.setTwo(2);
           tw7.getItem().add(ite7_1);

           ite7_1 = new Component1.TwentySeven.Item();
           ite7_1.setOne(3);
           ite7_1.setTwo(4);
           tw7.getItem().add(ite7_1);

           ite7_1 = new Component1.TwentySeven.Item();
           ite7_1.setOne(5);
           ite7_1.setTwo(6);
           tw7.getItem().add(ite7_1);

           comp1.setTwentySeven(tw7);
           Component1.Hundred hund = new Component1.Hundred();
           Component1.Hundred.Item hund_1 = new Component1.Hundred.Item();
           hund_1.setOne(7);
           hund_1.setTwo(8);
           hund.getItem().add(hund_1);

           hund_1 = new Component1.Hundred.Item();
           hund_1.setOne(9);
           hund_1.setTwo(10);
           hund.getItem().add(hund_1);

           hund_1 = new Component1.Hundred.Item();
           hund_1.setOne(11);
           hund_1.setTwo(12);
           hund.getItem().add(hund_1);

           comp1.setHundred(hund);
           JAXBElement<Component1> osy = new JAXBElement<Component1>(osx  , Component1.class, comp1  );
           marshaller.marshal(comp1 , xsw);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

My XSD (made by Altova 2017 in text) is :